# Error seeding my database using seed_dump gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I used the gem, seed_dump to dump and and seed my database when moving from computer to computer. Though I was able to dump my data when it came to seeding I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/bowser/rails_projects/project_one/db/seeds.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting end-of-input
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Aside from having the file created none of the code was altered which makes me wonder if it was outputted correctly to begin with.

**Seed File**

```
Article.create!([
  {title: "RailsConf", body: "RailsConf is the official gathering for Rails developers..", published_at: "2013-04-13 00:00:00", excerpt: nil, location: nil, user_id: nil},
  {title: "Introduction to Active Record", body: "Active Record is Rail's default ORM..", published_at: "2014-08-14 00:00:00", excerpt: nil, location: nil, user_id: nil}
])
#<Class:0x007f92d712a108>.create!([
  {article_id: 1, category_id: 1}
])
Category.create!([
  {name: "sports"}
])
#<Class:0x007f92d70e2268>.create!([
  {article_id: 1, category_id: 1}
])
Profile.create!([
  {user_id: nil, name: "Joe", birthday: "2014-08-14", color: "blue", twitter: "twitter.com/joe"}
])
```

Comment: what `#<Class:0x007f92d712a108>.create!` means?

Comment: Not sure. Like I said this is what was created when I ran rake:db:dump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bad News!**

`seed_dump` [doesn't work](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump/issues/26) for the tables which don't have corresponding Models, e.g. HABTM mapper table.

In your case, its problem of HABTM mapper table which has columns `article_id` and `category_id` but as per implementation, it doesn't have model so `seed_dump` is adding wrong code to `db/seed.rb`

```
#<Class:0x007f92d70e2268>.create!([
  {article_id: 1, category_id: 1}
])
```

**It'll not work** when you will try to run `rake db:seed`.

**Alternative solution:**

Just extract database dump from your server and add use that on new machine by importing it into your db server on that new machine.

If you are using `mysql`, you will need to do:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > FILE_NAME.sql
```

It will ask you for mysql password. Enter that and it will export data to FILE_NAME.sql

Now for importing db on another machine,

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME < FILE_NAME.sql
```

More about [db import/export](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-and-reset-a-root-password-in-mysql)

Comment: As far as the alternative solution what would be the best method in extracting (exporting) and importing the db? Is there a rake command that would allow me to do this?

Comment: I'm using the default sqlite3. Would there be any difference?

Comment: If you are using sqlite, you must have your database located in `db` directory of app itself. No need to export and import, just place that database into `db` directory